# How do I take a converted file (pdf to html), and open it locally in a new tab in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically I have a django app that communicates with a chrome extension.  I have a bunch of functionality that interfaces with normal HTML pages that's all done by the extension.  I want to allow users to have the same functionalities for PDF files.  I have a python script which translates the pdf file into an html page.

The problem I run into is when the pdfs are open locally within chrome.

Like the following `file:///home/wcr5048/Downloads/sample_pdf.pdf`

This is my current solution, it basically gets the html and replaces all the current html, which is just an embedded pdf, and replaces it with the converted pdf(html).  But I run into an issue because the "url" isn't really a url, and therefore I can't append html to something that doesn't exist.

```
function convert_to_html(request) {
    console.log('converting to html...');
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = request.data;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        detail: 'refresh'
    });
}
```

**What I don't want to happen is to download a file just like the pdf but one that's been converted into html.  I would rather have everything happen automatically.**

I only see two possible options:

1. I create a unique link for the converted pdf file for every user, and then send the raw html string to populate the corresponding view.
2. I somehow tell the extension to use a popup to cover the entire width of the screen, and then populate it with the data.

Are there any suggested solutions that would be a better fit, and if not, which would be a better solution.

Thanks for viewing

Comment: I can't see from your code where URL becomes a problem, and you need to show what that refresh command does.

Comment: The refresh function only adds functionality to the html page, it doesn't have anything to do with converting the file, it's merely to enable additional functionality after it gets converted.